# Azure AD - AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have followed 
 [this](https://github.com/dushyantgill/VipSwapper/tree/master/TrainingPoint/TrainingPoint)  example app, and it works fine for the most part... However, in the case of one of the users I have created for the purpose of testing, an exception is thrown in the following code block:

```
public static string LookupDisplayNameOfAADObject(string objectId)
{
        string objectDisplayName = null;
        string tenantId = (ClaimsPrincipal.Current).FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string signedInUserID = (ClaimsPrincipal.Current).FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string userObjectID = (ClaimsPrincipal.Current).FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]);


        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Authority"], tenantId), new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));

        string test = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Authority"], tenantId);


        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphApiIdentifier"], credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));



        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string doQueryUrl = string.Format(
            "{0}{1}/directoryObjects/{2}?api-version={3}",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphApiIdentifier"], tenantId,
            objectId, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphApiVersion"]);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, doQueryUrl);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = response.Content;
            string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic directoryObject = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(responseString);
            if (directoryObject != null) objectDisplayName = string.Format("{0} ({1})", directoryObject.displayName, directoryObject.objectType);
        }

        return objectDisplayName;
}
```

- AcquireTokenSilent throws a AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException but only in the case of this single user...
- The exception mesage is : "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken".

The AcquireToken method will prompt the user to log in again, and I am trying to avoid prompting the user, and as stated, this happens only in the case of this one user.
How should this situation be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this exception, it means ADAL was unable to locate an access token or refresh token in its cache that it could use.

Ensure your token cache is not in-memory so it doesn't get wiped in case of process restart. EDIT: I see that it is in a DB so that should not be an issue.

Another thing you could do is increase the session duration. ASP.NET by default limits it to 20 minutes, and OpenIdConnect by default follows that. It means it just erases those tokens after 20 minutes even though the refresh token is usable much longer.

For that you will need to modify the OpenIdConnect middleware registration in Startup.Auth.cs like so:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // ... Rest removed for brevity
                UseTokenLifetime = false
            });
```

Then in web.config set the session time to what you want:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="720" /><!-- 12 hour session duration -->
</system.web>
```

Other than that, if you get a silent acquisition exception, the only thing you can do is redirect the user to AAD to re-authenticate so you get new access and refresh tokens.

Comment: Although the answer you provided did give me insight as to what I am dealing with, the solution didn't fix the problem... Even when I re-log as this user, the exception is still thrown. The thing that bugs me the most about this is the fact that this only happens to this one user... Since I'm working with dummy data here, I quess I'll just delete the db and start a new ...

Comment: Bummer :( You should try to debug the token cache and see what is going on with it. It should be able to find the token but is unable to for some reason..

Comment: Great! :) Good to hear!

Comment: The problem was due to the getter on the model I am using:
`[NotMapped]
        public string CreatedByDisplay
        {
            get
            {
                if (CreatedBy == null) return null;
                else return Util.GraphUtil.LookupDisplayNameOfAADObject(CreatedBy);
            }
        }`
The value of CreatedBy is shady. Thanks, cheers !